# PowerBI subscription notifications for the latest changes

Tags: email, notifications, powerbi, updates, subscription

I was wondering if it is possible to notify / send an email to the PowerBI report subscribers whenever there is a new change to the data in the report?

I saw that the only current options are for periodic notifications (hourly, daily, etc.) and after refreshing, but they are not that helpful. The problem is that there might not be updates once the data refreshes and this notification would be useless. I am interested in sending notifications once new data comes in.

Has anyone had this problem and found a solution or a work-around?

Best regards,
Denis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work-around solution (which is not that elegant).

I created a measure that computes the desired number and displayed it in a card. I pinned this card in PowerBI Service (after publishing the report) as a scoreboard / goal. Then I have set an alarm with a specific threshold which triggers an email notification once this threshold is exceeded.

I created a flow in Power Automate which checks if the threshold has been exceeded and automatically send a PDF to the users.

I could have stopped at the goal alarm notification but this would mean that the users have to set their own alarm individually & manually. By creating the Automate flow, I only have to add their email to the list and they would be notified whenever the threshold is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

Report Subscriptions are, by design, simplistic.

Power Automate provides the building blocks for many more sophisticated subscription scenarios.  So with

[Export and email a Power BI report with Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-automate-power-bi-report-export)

And

[Unlocking new self-service BI scenarios with ExecuteQueries support in Power Automate](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/unlocking-new-self-service-bi-scenarios-with-executequeries-support-in-power-automate/)

You could run a query on a schedule to determine if any new data is available, and if so Export and email a report.

Comment: Hello David,

Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to combine some of the things from both of them, but it is not the direct solution.